# Wordpress stylesheet isn't being added

Tags: theme-development

I have recently started to learn WordPress and after learning how to use it at basic level I immediately started to learn how to develop templates since this is what interested me from the start when I started to learn it.

I am reading [WordPress 3 Complete](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849514100) and at Chapter 6 the book guides you to develop your first basic theme. The only problem is that it seems that my theme is not taking the style sheet. I have tried to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

and

```
<style type="text/css">@import url("style.css");</style>
```

None of them seem to get the style on the page. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure WordPress finds the directory where your theme is. There is a useful function doing all the work for you: [`bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you can enqueue the style in your `functions.php` file (this is my new preference):

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css', get_stylesheet_uri(), false );
```

Comment: I think I agree with you ... but is it the best method for theme developers?

Comment: @damien, I can swear that there was either a WordPress idea or trac ticket where people were debating whether to start doing this with the WordPress "core" themes (the Twenty ___ ones), but now I can't find it. If everyone enqueued it with the 'style' `$handle` then it would be easy to use that handle with child themes or plugins.

Comment: Thing is ... IMHO theme developers want to know HTML CSS and JS so a basic function like wp_enqueue_style might be too technical so you end up with <link rel ....

Comment: (This should really be in a chat. Sorry.) I've got to say that at this point you HAVE to be able to at least read basic PHP to do real, responsible theme development. If you want to use jQuery UI, for instance, you have to use `wp_enqueue_style` as well. So I think it's not an issue to use it one more time.